# htaccess rewrite for params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do .htaccess rewrite for example:

`http://example.com/abc123` to `http://example.com/index.html?code=abc123`

The Rule below works for `http://example.com/abc123/` (with the trailing `/`)

```
RewriteRule "(.*)/$" "/index.php?code=$1"
```

But when I remove it the trailing `/` it fails with...

```
RewriteRule "(.*)$" "/index.php?code=$1"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? If you remove the trailing slash in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ then, if you include the trailing slash on the request then the _substitution_ will be `/index.php?code=abc123/` - is that the problem? Do you want to ignore the trailing slash (although that potentially results in _duplicate content_)?

Comment: Using the second rule, and going to http://example.com/abc123 I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the second rule, and going to `example.com/abc123` I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Ah yes, your second rule will result in a rewrite loop, since it will be triggered again for `/index.php?code=abc123/` and then `/index.php?code=index.php` etc. etc. The first rule does not loop endlessly because the trailing slash does not appear in the rewritten request.

You could make the second rule work by introducing a *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^code=
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?code=$1 [L]
```

This simply checks the query string to make sure the `code` URL param is not already present on the URL, which is added by the internal rewrite.

I've removed the quotes around the arguments, as they aren't strictly necessary here. They are only really required if you have spaces in the argument values. The trailing `$` is also not required on this regex - unlike the previous rule that had a trailing slash.